How to hide an object from tagpdf and provide alt-text
When I compile this document, I get five dozen warnings from the tagpdf having to do with the qrcode. Is there a way I can hide the qrcode from tagpdf? Preferably this would include an option to provide alt-text.
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\mylink{https:tex.stackexchange.com}

\begin{document}
\qrcode{\mylink}             % How do I hide this qrcode from tagging?
\url{\mylink}
\end{document}


I can't test now and don't know which warnings you get, but you could try a picture environment around it (picture has an optional argument with the tagging code which knows an alt key).

@UlrikeFischer I'll have to play around with sizing and placement, since I've never used picture, but that does suppress the warnings, and the alt argument seems to work.

Yes picture more or less work, but it also suppresses the structure from the link, so should only be used with the nolink option. For more sophisticated tagging one should redefine the internal wrappers. I don't have internet on my laptop now, but can sent something later.

Maybe I don't know what you mean by "it also suppresses the structure from the link," but the qrcode link still seems to work. (Mouse-over preview displays it, clicking it opens the link.)

The link works, but there is no associated link structure element.

Well it isn't completly trivial as qrcode has not really suitable hooks (yet). Here an option. Remark: I'm not sure if tagging the qrcode as Figure with alternative text is the best solution, but the result in ngpdf.com looks imho ok. The most complicated part of the code is to get the BBox right (that allows ngpdf to extract the image).
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III},uncompress}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn\qr@savepos 
 {
  \tex_savepos:D 
  \RecordProperties{qr@save-\theqrcodecnt}{xpos,ypos}
  \tex_savepos:D 
 }
\cs_new:Npn \qr@diminbp #1 {\dim_to_decimal_in_bp:n {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{qrcodecnt}
\NewSocket{tagsupport/qrcode/begin}{0}
\NewSocket{tagsupport/qrcode/end}{0}
\NewSocketPlug{tagsupport/qrcode/begin}{tag}
 {%
   \leavevmode
   \tagmcend%
   \stepcounter{qrcodecnt}\qr@savepos%
   \ExpandArgs{e}\tagpdfsetup
     {role/new-attribute=
      {qrcode-\theqrcodecnt}
      {
       /O /Layout 
       /BBox [\qr@diminbp{\RefProperty{qr@save-\theqrcodecnt}{xpos}sp}
              \qr@diminbp{\RefProperty{qr@save-\theqrcodecnt}{ypos}sp-0.5\qr@desiredheight}
              \qr@diminbp{\RefProperty{qr@save-\theqrcodecnt}{xpos}sp+\qr@desiredheight} 
              \qr@diminbp{\RefProperty{qr@save-\theqrcodecnt}{ypos}sp+0.5\qr@desiredheight}] 
      }%
     }%
   \tagstructbegin{tag=Figure,alt=\qr@texttoencode,
    attribute=qrcode-\theqrcodecnt}%
   \tagmcbegin{}%
  }
  
\NewSocketPlug{tagsupport/qrcode/end}{tag} 
 {\tagmcend\tagstructend\tagmcbegin{}}
 
\AssignSocketPlug{tagsupport/qrcode/begin}{tag} 
\AssignSocketPlug{tagsupport/qrcode/end}{tag} 

\def\qrcode@hyperwrapper@hyperref#1{%
  \href{\qr@texttoencode}%
   {\UseTaggingSocket{qrcode/begin}\SuspendTagging{qrcode}%
    #1\ResumeTagging{qrcode}\UseTaggingSocket{qrcode/end}}}
 
\def\qrcode@hyperwrapper@nohyperref#1{%
  \UseTaggingSocket{qrcode/begin}\SuspendTagging{qrcode}%
  #1\ResumeTagging{qrcode}\UseTaggingSocket{qrcode/end}}

\patchcmd\qrcode@int{\relax}{\qrcode@hyperwrapper@nohyperref}{}{\fail}

\makeatother


\newcommand\mylink{https://tex.stackexchange.com}

\begin{document}


\qrcode{\mylink} 

\qrcode*{blabla}

\end{document}


Note: I have to use lualatex-dev to avoid errors.
But I'm curious, what does this do w.r.t. tagging that wrapping in picture does not?

It preserves the link structure (use ngpdf.com to check) and it is more automated.  (The BBox is imho a bit wrong but I don't have the time now to check how qrcode exactly places the baseline.)
